# Conditional redirect after update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, redirect

I would like to do a conditional update in ruby on rails 3.1
Where based on the location you came from, after update, an redirect will be done. 
Splitted my 1 big form in to separate smaller ones, so now the Idea is to redirect to the correct subform.

For example the form can be submitted from:

- profile basics form
- Profile details form

The only thing I could come up with is checking the action name and use that to redirect. But its very ugly and long code and not fully working either. What would be the railsway of doing this?

This is my controller update action:

```
def update

    @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|

     if @profile.update_attributes(params[:profile])
        format.html { redirect_to @profile, notice: 'Profile was successfully updated.' }
      else
        format.html {
          render :action => "edit_basics"
          #

        }
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just pass the redirect location as a hidden_field in the form, then have each form set it as needed:

```
redirect_to params[:redirect_location]
```

You could also do this using steps or something if you don't want to expose the raw string in your HTML:

```
redirect_to location_for_step(params[:step])
```

Comment: in view
`<%= hidden_field_tag :redirect_location, '/whatever/url' %>`